# MySQL link employee hours worked on each day against dates

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a table with employees details including hours they work on each day (shift work )

```
  empid   name  mon  tue  wed  thu  fri  sat sun
    1     Joe   8    10   6    10   6    0   0
    2     tim   10   8    6     6   0    10  0
    3     sam   0    8    8     8   0    8   8
```

and in the second  table  I would like to populate it using the hours from employee table link to the date. How do i link the hours from table one to the date for the  insert statement into table 2.

```
  empId       Date                                            hours
    1     2015/10/11 (this date is mon so hours would be)       8
    1     2015/10/12 (this date is tue so hours would be)      10
    2     2015/10/13 (this date is wed so hours would be)       6
```

Not sure how to I would go about this. Can this just be done with  MySQL or using PHP.

UPDATE THE INSERT STATEMENT I USE

```
    $startTime = strtotime($from);
$endTime = strtotime($to);
$values = array();
for($time = $startTime; $time <= $endTime; $time = strtotime('+1 day', $time))
{
   $thisDate = date('Y-m-d', $time);
   $values[] = "($user_id, '$thisDate')";

}
    $sql = sprintf(
   "INSERT INTO workhours (enpid, date) VALUES\n%s",
   implode(",\n", $values)
);
```

UPDATE TO TABLE STRUCTURE
Employee table:

```
empid     name   lastname
 1         Joe    Jones
 2         tim    good
```

employee hours:

```
id    empid  mon   tue   wed   thu   fri  sat   sun
1       1     8    10     6    10     6    0      0
2       2     10    8     6     6     0    10     0
```

What I need to do is get the hours for each day from table one and insert that value along side empId and Date into table 2 
Thanks

Comment: Your dates in your second table don't match up with the days of the week. If your dates are `Y/M/D`, the days are `S/Tu/Th`, but if it is `Y/D/M` they are `S/M/Tu`, not sure how you have `M/Tue/W` ind your example.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "link data", is it replication? Redundancy? Foreign reference?

Comment: @devlin carnate How should the table  structure be?

Comment: The date is Y-m-d  not sure how to go about this even with the table structure any suggestions would be great

Comment: @jonathanyoung - it's hard to give a concrete answer to the table structure without knowing your project requirements.  However, in general terms, I'd say an employee table should hold employee info (emp id, emp name, and any other employee related details).  I'd then have a separate table to track hours worked.  That table would have a record id, emp id (linked to the emp table), start and end datetime.  If you need to calc total hours or relate hours to a day of the week, I'd handle that outside the database.

Comment: @devlin carnate I see what you are saying but the only employee details are id first and last name so I did not think having the second table with hours is necessary. Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with Mysql Query.

```
insert into table2 (empId,date,hours)
select emp_id,
'2015/10/11' as date,
case dayname('2015/10/11')
    when 'Sunday' then sun
    when 'Monday' then mon
    when 'Tuesday' then tue
    when 'Wednesday' then wed
    when 'Thursday' then thu
    when 'Friday' then fri
    when 'Saturday' then sat
else 0 end as hours
from table1
```

Comment: I have had  someone say that the database structure is rubbish do you think that the employee table  with each day and hours for each shift if Ok. Then table 2 insert empId and date along with the hours for each day. Your opinion would be good thanks. When I insert the date into the database i have date range I have update the question with the insert statement

Comment: Thank you for that works on a single date. How to I combine your insert statement with my date range insert statement. I  have updated my original question, Basically I have a date range Eg. 2015/10/11 to 2015/10/16 $from $to Then it splits the range into each day there inserts int the date base. Thanks for your time

Comment: You help me with the original question which works great on a single day. I would like your answer to work in a range of dates at the moment i us php to do this but would just lick to use MySQL Eg date range 2015-10-11 to 2015-10-20 any ideas or shoul i setup a new question?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I wouldn't store the formatted employee hours in a table, just the raw info of employee id, date, and hours. With queries and/or PHP I can then format the data into any format i want, such as a weekly calendar format. It's better DB practices to do it this way.